# Select date out of string containing date and other characters

Tags: regex, powershell, datetime

I'm trying to query a courier web page for shipping information with a tracking number using Windows PowerShell. There's no API available for this particular courier so I'm currently just pulling the HTML of each individual webpage using Invoke-RestMethod.

I'm trying to select the pickup date from each page.

I'm able to select the pickup date on the page however the string I'm selecting is containing other characters, for example:

```
30/10/2018</td>
<td><span
```

The reason for this is I'm using this to get the date in some shape/form:

```
$pickupdatemessy = $httpresponse.Substring(25448,30)
```

This gives me the date in some shape or form, however for each page, the date might be in a different place in the variable. I'm trying to simply strip the date to another variable so it will look like 30/10/2018. I've experimented with RegEx however I'm not having luck and now looking for help.

Comment: Are you able to consistently rip out the date and junk data? Does it always look like `30/10/2018</td><td><span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we will do a simple regex \d = digit, {2} = How many digits, inside a (expression). Then for each match with get the value and validate if its a real date by parsing the date into a `datetime` if the parsing fails then we know its not a date with the format `DayDay/MonthMonth/YearYearYearYear` aka `dd/MM/yyyy` If no failure then output the value of the regex match.

```
@"
30/10/2018</td>
<td><span
"@ | Select-String -Pattern "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})" -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | %{
    try{
        [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.value,"dd/MM/yyyy", $null)
    }catch{}
}
```

output would be : `30/10/2018`

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. It did end up saying a full date: "Tuesday, 30 October 2018 12:00:00 AM" However I modified your recommendations to the following and it's working: $variablecontainingdate | Select-String -Pattern "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})" -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value